# android sdk install error EPIPE

Tags: android, node.js, meteor, android-sdk-tools

I'm on Meteor 1.1.0.2 Mac Yosemite, and I have this error when I try to install the android SDK for Meteor

```
$ meteor install-sdk android
Installing Android bundle
✓ A JDK is installed
Installing Android Platform tools

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)
```

if somebody got an idea about what might cause it.

Comment: how much disk space do you have left?

Comment: 408 Go. Do you think it's a storage capacity problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I get same error. Try to run it with sudo command: `sudo meteor install-sdk android`, it works for some people.